# Difference between assigning a value versus assigning another variable

Tags: typescript

I have two objects p and q. Object q has one extra property 'b':

```js
let p = {a:1}
let q = {a:1, b:2}
```

Now, if I assign q to p. No problem:

```js
p = q           // ok
```

However, the following has type error:

```js
p = {a:1, b:2}  // not ok
```

Error:

```
Type '{ a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type '{ a: number; }'.
(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBADhC8EG8CGAuAjAGggXwFCkgEc5FVMIAjFAJj1wgehOMdcYHp2IB7Aa3sYx4ydFiq0GnCADtukPriA)

In both cases, I am reassigning an object with extra properties to p. My understanding of duck-typing is that assigning objects are allowed as long as there is no missing property. But then why does the compiler complain in the latter case?

Comment: Excess props checking only happens on object literals.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, but why is checking done on one case but not the other?

Comment: Because in all the other cases it's not definitely a mistake, that value is available through other interfaces that _do_ give access to those excess properties. In the first case you can do q.b, in the second case b is unreachable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, please elaborate if you could. I still don't understand because as far as p is concerned, adding an extra property is irrelevant because the extra property is never accessible even if it exists (by the way of a later object literal reassignment).

Comment: Yes, so it's at best pointless and at worst downright misleading, so the compiler tells you that. Research "typescript excess property checks" if you'd like to know more.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you for pointing out where to look.